# Rails 3 validates rule based on action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

This seems like a simple question but I can't seem to find an answer short of writing custom validators. I have this validator

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :length => { :minimum => 5}
```

there are more rules applied such as some regex for complexity, but this gives the gist.

The issue is that I only want presence applied on create, everything else needs to be on create and update. Because the user may not be changing a password when updating their information.

I tried splitting the rules

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :on => :create
validates :password, # The rest of the rules
```

This resulted in all rules being ignored for update. Is there a simple way to apply only one rule to create and the rest to everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try keeping it in one line, but applying `:on => :create` to just the `:presence` check:

```
validates :password, :presence => {:on => :create}, :confirmation => true, :length => { :minimum => 5}
```

However, I'm not sure it makes sense to always require a minimum length, but not always require presence -- if you update an existing record with a blank password, it's going to fail validations anyway since the length is 0.

Comment: Good point. I may have to look at it a bit deeper. Some of the requirements of an entered password can fail if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that the problem is that the validate :password call is not additive.  Can you switch the presence check to:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on=>:create
```

And then keep your other validations using the validate.  Does that work?