# Rails: How to set different validation rules on creation and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, dynamic

I have a text field that can be empty when created, but not when updated.

**How can I do that in rails: Different validation rules depending on action?**

The idea behind this, is to allow an admin to create a blank issue ticket, to be filled by a user.

Here is my original model (issue.rb):

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :content, :status

validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 2048 }
validates :status, :inclusion => { :in => %w(WAITING REJECTED ON OFF) }

belongs_to :user

end
```

How can I set `:presence => true` of `:content` only when updating, but not when creating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:on => :create` in your validation statement.

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899116/rails-3-validates-rule-based-on-action).