# How not to allow validation for a specific action in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this password validation in my user.model.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true,
            format: {:with => /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[&%$#@*])[a-zA-Z0-9&%$#@*]{8,}$/,
            :multiline => true, :message => I18n.t('invalid_password')}
end
```

I want this validation to be called in each and every method but not in my update action.

I have a users_controller.rb that has a create and update action. I want it to check in the create action but not in the update action.

I also have a password_resets_controller.rb in which I want it to check in both create and update actions but not in users_controller update action. I am using the authlogic gem. Both controllers use the same model.

Please guide me on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899116/rails-3-validates-rule-based-on-action

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3 validates rule based on action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899116/rails-3-validates-rule-based-on-action)

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :password, :presence => {:on => :create}
```

**OR**

```
##here new_user is a method that you can create and use condionally
## or validates_presence_of :password, :if => :new_user?
validates_presence_of :password, :unless => :new_user?

def new_user?
  //your code
end
```

**OR** Using [with_options](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles

  # Normal Validations 
  validates_presence_of   :password


  with_options :if => :customer? do |customer|
    customer.validates_presence_of :password
  end

  def customer?
    roles.any? { |role| role.name == "customer" }
  end 
end
```

Comment: I am having this in my users_controller.rb update action `@user.update(user_params)`. How I will skip validation in this

Comment: you cannot skip validaitons on update...you need to use update_attribute or use validate:false .give it a try

Comment: OP wants to skip validation in model definition. `update_attributes` is something else - she doesn't ask about ways to not validate object

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most close answer can be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :password, presence: true, if: :not_persisted?

   def not_persisted?
     !self.persisted?  
   end
end
```

This code will actually trigger the validation only if the object is not persisted (on create)